# network broadcast from bluestacks - Beacon-v1

Tags: bluestacks

The latest update of Bluestacks is sending a network broadcast every 2 seconds from port 10505.

Beacon-v1|pcName|WindowsPC 
OpenSensor-v2|54321

to IP 255.255.255.255

this wasnt happening with the previous version. is this some autosync announcement waiting to talk with another device? i dont want bluestacks talking to other networked devices unless i tell it to do so. i havent checked off or agreed to anything yet that says it requires a network broadcast like this.

even if it's only 53 bytes it's still network pollution to me. how can i turn this off until i actually want it ? thanks

```
package com.example.test5;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBAdapter {

private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";    
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "TestDB";   //Database Name 'TestDB'
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION =1; //Change Version to upgrade db

private final Context context; 

private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBAdapter(Context ctx) 
{
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {  

        db.execSQL("create table USER(Id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,USER_ID TEXT NOT NULL,USER_NAME TEXT NOT NULL,PASSWORD TEXT NOT NULL, ACTIVE_YN TEXT NOT NULL default 'Y')");

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
    int newVersion) 
    { 
         db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS USER"); 
         onCreate(db); 
    }
}

//---opens the database---
public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
{
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

//---closes the database---    
public void close() 
{
    DBHelper.close();        
}

//---insert a User into the database---
public void insertUser(String USER_ID,String USER_NAME,String PASSWORD) 
{  
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put("USER_ID", USER_ID);
    initialValues.put("USER_NAME", USER_NAME);
    initialValues.put("PASSWORD", PASSWORD);                      
    db.insert("USER", null, initialValues);                  
}

//---updates 
public boolean updateUserStatusById(String USER_NAME,String USER_ID ) 
{
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put("USER_NAME", USER_NAME);
    return db.update("USER", args, 
            "USER_ID='" + USER_ID+"'", null) > 0;
}  

//executing query and it returns fields which are specified in the query ..........
public Cursor getQueryResult(String MY_QUERY) throws SQLException 
{                
    return db.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, null); 
} 

}
```

Nandakishore P

Answer (score 1):

I find this to be an annoyance as well and would like to turn it off.  So far, I have found that the offending executable is:

C:\program files (x86)\bluestacks\hd-frontend.exe

And in C:\ProgramData\BlueStacks\Logs\BlueStacksUsers.log there are entries for:

2015-12-10 08:46:56.378000 HD-Frontend( 2632: 4588):     1 INFO OpenSensor: Beacon port 10505, interval 2000, host name MYHOSTNAME

Having a block entry every two seconds on my firewall is unacceptable!

Comment: I stopped using BlueStack and moved to Genymotion, anyway thanks for ur answer.